# Socket throws nullreferenceexception while asynchrously receiving data

Tags: c#, sockets

So I have my server-client protocol and they cannot perfectly but when the client has received data from the server it throws a nullreference exception, this code handles the received data:

```
private void AsyncReceive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        int bytesTransferred;

        try
        {
            bytesTransferred = _handle.EndReceive(result); //throws the exception

            if (bytesTransferred <= 0)
                throw new Exception("no bytes transferred");
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Disconnect();
            return;
        }

        byte[] received = new byte[bytesTransferred];

        try
        {
            Array.Copy(_readBuffer, received, received.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnClientFail(ex);
            return;
        }

        lock (_readBuffers)
        {
            _readBuffers.Enqueue(received);
        }

        lock (_readingPacketsLock)
        {
            if (!_readingPackets)
            {
                _readingPackets = true;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AsyncReceive);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            _handle.BeginReceive(_readBuffer, 0, _readBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, AsyncReceive, null);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnClientFail(ex);
        }
    }
```

So the line `bytesTransferred = _handle.EndReceive(result);` throws the exception. I should also note that I am NOT using an ordinary socket, i'm using a ProxySocket(extensioh of the socket class) which can be found here: [ProxySocket](https://github.com/poma/ProxySocket) and here is how the client starts the datahandling: 
        `   protected void Connect(string ip, ushort port)
        {
            try
            {
                Disconnect();

```
            _handle = new ProxySocket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _handle.SetKeepAliveEx(KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME);
            _handle.ProxyType = ProxyTypes.Https;
            _handle.ProxyEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 54973);
            _handle.Connect(ip, port);

            if (_handle.Connected)
            {
                _handle.BeginReceive(_readBuffer, 0, _readBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, AsyncReceive, null);
                OnClientState(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnClientFail(ex);
        }
    }   `
```

If I need to provide more data, you can ask me in a comment.

Thanks

This is result:

```
+       _handle {Org.Mentalis.Network.ProxySocket.ProxySocket}  Org.Mentalis.Network.ProxySocket.ProxySocket
    bytesTransferred    0   int
```

- result  {System.Net.Sockets.OverlappedAsyncResult}  System.IAsyncResult {System.Net.Sockets.OverlappedAsyncResult}
- AsyncCallback   {Method = {Void AsyncReceive(System.IAsyncResult)}} System.AsyncCallback
      AsyncState  null    object
- AsyncWaitHandle {System.Threading.ManualResetEvent} System.Threading.WaitHandle {System.Threading.ManualResetEvent}
      CompletedSynchronously  false   bool
      IsCompleted true    bool
- Static members
- Non-Public members
- this    {_4ng3l.Core.Networking.G0DClient}  _4ng3l.Core.Networking.Client {_4ng3l.Core.Networking.G0DClient}

Comment: You sure the `result` parameter isn't null?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'll post the output when I place a breakpoint, it doesnt seem null to me EDIT: oh damn that look great.... maybe its a bit too bad